# Finding % of remaining students in the class would be girls?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In class of $120$ students, boys constitute $40$% of total. If $\dfrac 13^{rd}$ of boys and $4$ girls drop out of class to join a camp , what % of remaining students in the class would be girls ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Total number of students, $ T = 120 $. Number of boys, $ N_B = 40\% \text{ of } T = 0.4 * 120 = 48 $. Thus, number of girls, $ N_G = 120 - 48 = 72 $.

Now, $ \frac{1}{3}^{rd} $ of boys are leaving, $ \implies (\frac{1}{3} * 48) + 4 = 16 + 4 = 20 $ students are leaving.

New count $ N = 120 - 20 = 100 $. New percentage of girls population:

$$ P_G = \dfrac{72 - 4}{N} * 100 \% \ = 68 \% $$

Comment: can explain Pg Formula , how did you have 72 ? what is name of this formula ?

Comment: @SSK There is no name for this formula, AFAIK. The percentages are calculated using the following: $$ \dfrac{\text{Number of girls}}{\text{Total number of students}} $$ Originally, there were $72$ girls of which $4$ left for the camp. Hence, $ 72 - 4 $ in numerator.

Comment: why you took N ]

Comment: @SSK Because the percentage is to be calculated for new number of students, which is $ N $.